# print specific xml node value in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to print node value, but it's print nothing. Here is the code:

```
package require dom;
set XML "
    <top number='1'>
        <a>Name</a>
        <b>589</b>
        <email>name@example.com</email>
        <website/>
        <parts>
            <widget sku='XYZ123' />
            <widget sku='ABC789' />
        </parts>
    </top>
"
set doc [::dom::parse $XML]
set root [$doc cget -documentElement]
set node [$root cget -firstChild]
set node [$root cget -nextSibling]
set node [$root cget -firstChild]
puts "[$node cget -nodeValue]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [TclDOM documentation](http://tclxml.sourceforge.net/tclxml/3.2/tcldom.html#id22609), you should use the `stringValue` method to get the string content of a node.

```
puts [$node stringValue]
```

You probably should use the `selectNode` method to choose the element to print instead of doing so manually; XPath is much simpler to use than straight DOM:

```
set doc [dom::parse $XML]
set node [[$doc cget -documentElement] selectNode "/top/b"]
puts [$node stringValue]
```

Comment: [Donal Fwllows](http://stackoverflow.com/users/301832/donal-fellows) Thanks for the help. Could I use this approach to iterate over the entire XML?

Comment: Probably, but I can't test because of a bug in my installation of TclDOM. (I could certainly do it with tDOM.)